# How to identify why the mail is not getting triggered from Oracle Database end? Does the DB have any logs to keep track of it?

Tags: sql, oracle

The procedure (PMNT_API_MAILER) is mentioned below.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PMNT_API_MAILER(PMNT_DATE IN DATE)

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE

strMailHost   VARCHAR2(50);

strMailPort   VARCHAR2(4);

strHeader    VARCHAR2(4000);

strMessage   VARCHAR2(4000);

nPos      NUMBER;

strFrom     VARCHAR2(100);

strSendTo    VARCHAR2(1000);

strCCTo     VARCHAR2(1000);

strSubject   VARCHAR2(500);

strSendTo_BAF  VARCHAR2(1000);

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



P_TEXT     clob;--VARCHAR2(4000);

P_HTML     clob;

V_SUM_LOAN_PRIN_ADV  NUMBER := 0;

V_Count     Number;

V_BusinessDate VARCHAR(20);

v_error varchar2(1000);

P_DATE     DATE := PMNT_DATE;

v_cnt_cu    number := 0;

attachments PKG_SEND_MAIL.ARRAY_ATTACHMENTS := PKG_SEND_MAIL.ARRAY_ATTACHMENTS();

V_REJECT_DATA CLOB;

V_SUCCESS_DATA CLOB;



CURSOR REJ IS

  SELECT a.agreementid,a.downloadid,b.chequeid,b.BANK_REJ_REASON

  FROM lea_h2hpayment_hdr a, lea_h2hpayment_dtl b

  where a.downloadid = b.downloadid

  and a.download_date = P_DATE

  and a.pmnt_method = 'API'

  and a.status = 'A'

  and b.BANK_REJ_REASON is not null;



CURSOR SUCC IS

  SELECT a.agreementid,a.downloadid,b.chequeid,b.BANK_TXN_REF_NO

  FROM lea_h2hpayment_hdr a, lea_h2hpayment_dtl b

  where a.downloadid = b.downloadid

  and a.download_date = P_DATE

  and a.pmnt_method = 'API'

  and a.status = 'A'

  and b.BANK_TXN_REF_NO is not null;





 BEGIN

 v_error :=null;

  

BEGIN



 select CONF_VALUE

 into strMailHost

 from WS_PMNT_CONFIG

 WHERE CONF_KEY = 'MAIL_HOST'

 and status = 'A';



  select CONF_VALUE

 into strMailPort

 from WS_PMNT_CONFIG

 WHERE CONF_KEY = 'MAIL_PORT'

 and status = 'A';



  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN

  v_error := 'Error while fetching data from WS_PMNT_CONFIG' || sqlerrm;

END;



BEGIN

 SELECT EMAIL

 INTO strFrom

 FROM APIPMT_MAIL_RECEPIENTS

 WHERE FROM_TO ='F'

 AND ROWNUM = 1;



  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN

  v_error := 'Error while fetching sender mail from APIPMT_MAIL_RECEPIENTS' || sqlerrm;

  return;

END;



strHeader  := 'Date: ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'dd Mon yy hh24:mi:ss') ;

strSubject := 'Payment records processed via API on ' || to_char(P_DATE,'dd-MON-yyyy');



P_HTML := '<HTML><BODY bgcolor="white">

      <TABLE BORDER=0>

      <font color="black" face="Tahoma" SIZE="2" point-size=100 weight=600>

      <TR><TD colspan="2">Dear Team,

      <BR>

      <BR>

      </TD></TR>

      <TR><TD colspan="2">Please find below information related to Payment Disbursement :<BR></TD></TR>

       <TR></TR>

       <BR>

      <TR><TD colspan="2">1. Success file<BR></TD></TR>

      <BR>

      <TR><TD colspan="2">2. Reject file<BR></TD></TR>

      </font></TABLE>';



P_TEXT := '';



P_TEXT := '<BR>';



P_HTML := P_HTML || P_TEXT;



P_TEXT := '';



P_TEXT := '<TABLE BORDER=0>

      <font color="black" face="Tahoma" SIZE="2" point-size=100 weight=600>

      <TR><TD colspan="2">Thanks & Regards</TD></TR>

      <TR><TD colspan="2">IT Team</TD></TR></font></TABLE>';



P_HTML := P_HTML || P_TEXT ;



P_HTML := P_HTML || '</BODY></HTML>';





SELECT LISTAgg(EMAIL,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY EMAIL)

into strSendTo

FROM APIPMT_MAIL_RECEPIENTS

where status = 'A'

and from_to = 'T';



V_SUCCESS_DATA := 'LAN ID,CHQ ID,BATCH ID,UTR'||chr(13)||chr(10);

FOR S IN SUCC LOOP

  V_SUCCESS_DATA := V_SUCCESS_DATA ||

           S.AGREEMENTID||','||S.CHEQUEID||','||S.DOWNLOADID||','||S.BANK_TXN_REF_NO||chr(13)||chr(10);

END LOOP;

V_REJECT_DATA := 'LAN ID,CHQ ID,BATCH ID,Reject Reason'||chr(13)||chr(10);

FOR R IN REJ LOOP

  V_REJECT_DATA := V_REJECT_DATA ||

           R.AGREEMENTID||','||R.CHEQUEID||','||R.DOWNLOADID||','||R.BANK_REJ_REASON||chr(13)||chr(10);

END LOOP;



attachments.extend(2);



attachments(1).attach_name := 'Reject_'||PMNT_DATE||'.csv';

attachments(1).data_type := 'text/plain';

attachments(1).attach_content := V_REJECT_DATA;



attachments(2).attach_name := 'Success_'||PMNT_DATE||'.csv';

attachments(2).data_type := 'text/plain';

attachments(2).attach_content := V_SUCCESS_DATA;



PKG_SEND_MAIL.SEND_MAIL ( strFrom,strSendTo,strSubject,P_HTML,strCCTo,attachments ,'text/html', strMailHost, strMailPort);



trap('End SEND_MAIL');



  EXCEPTION



  WHEN UTL_SMTP.INVALID_OPERATION THEN

  v_error:='Invalid Operation in SMTP transaction.'||SQLERRM;



WHEN UTL_SMTP.TRANSIENT_ERROR THEN

  v_error:='Temporary problems in sending email - try again later.'||SQLERRM;



WHEN UTL_SMTP.PERMANENT_ERROR THEN

  v_error:='Errors in code for SMTP transaction.'||SQLERRM;



WHEN OTHERS THEN

  v_error:=' Error Occured while sending Mail.'||SQLERRM;

   

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_error);

 END;



 END;
```

The above proc is dependent on another proc named PKG_SEND_MAIL

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY PKG_SEND_MAIL AS



PROCEDURE SEND_MAIL(

v_from_name  VARCHAR2,

v_to_name   VARCHAR2,

v_subject   VARCHAR2,

v_message_body VARCHAR2,

v_cc_name   VARCHAR2 DEFAULT '',

attachments  array_attachments DEFAULT NULL,

v_message_type VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'text/plain',

v_smtp_ser  varchar2 ,

v_smtp_port   varchar2

) AS

 v_smtp_server    VARCHAR2(20) := v_smtp_ser;

 n_smtp_server_port NUMBER    := v_smtp_port;

 conn        utl_smtp.connection;

 v_boundry      VARCHAR2(20) := 'SECBOUND';

 n_offset      NUMBER    := 0;

 n_amount      NUMBER    := 1900;

 v_final_to_name   CLOB     := '';

 v_final_cc_name   CLOB     := '';

 v_mail_address   VARCHAR2(100);

 v_error_msg     varchar2(4000 byte);



  BEGIN

  conn := utl_smtp.open_connection(v_smtp_server,n_smtp_server_port);

   utl_smtp.helo(conn, v_smtp_server);

   utl_smtp.mail(conn, v_from_name);



  -- Add all recipient

  v_final_to_name := v_to_name;

  v_final_to_name := replace(v_final_to_name, ' ');

   v_final_to_name := replace(v_final_to_name, ',', ';');

  LOOP

   n_offset := n_offset + 1;

  v_mail_address := regexp_substr(v_final_to_name, '[^;]+', 1, n_offset);

   EXIT WHEN v_mail_address IS NULL;

  utl_smtp.rcpt(conn, v_mail_address);

  END LOOP;



  -- Add all recipient

  v_final_cc_name := v_cc_name;

   v_final_cc_name := replace(v_final_cc_name, ' ');

   v_final_cc_name := replace(v_final_cc_name, ',', ';');

   n_offset := 0;

    LOOP

    n_offset := n_offset + 1;

      v_mail_address := regexp_substr(v_final_cc_name, '[^;]+', 1, n_offset);

      EXIT WHEN v_mail_address IS NULL;

      utl_smtp.rcpt(conn, v_mail_address);

      END LOOP;



        -- Open data

       utl_smtp.open_data(conn);



        -- Message info

         utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('To: ' || v_final_to_name || UTL_TCP.crlf));

          utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Cc: ' || v_final_cc_name || UTL_TCP.crlf));

            utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Date: ' || to_char(sysdate, 'Dy, DD Mon YYYY hh24:mi:ss') || UTL_TCP.crlf));

            utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('From: ' || v_from_name || UTL_TCP.crlf));

             utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Subject: ' || v_subject || UTL_TCP.crlf));

             utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('MIME-Version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.crlf));

             utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="' || v_boundry || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf));



              -- Message body

              utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('--' || v_boundry || UTL_TCP.crlf));

               utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Content-Type: ' || v_message_type || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf));

               utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw(v_message_body || UTL_TCP.crlf));



                -- Attachment Part

               IF attachments IS NOT NULL

                THEN

                 FOR i IN attachments.FIRST .. attachments.LAST

                 LOOP

                -- Attach info

                  utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('--' || v_boundry || UTL_TCP.crlf));

  utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Content-Type: ' || attachments(i).data_type

            || ' name="'|| attachments(i).attach_name || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf));

  utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'

            || attachments(i).attach_name || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf));



-- Attach body

  n_offset := 1;

  WHILE n_offset < dbms_lob.getlength(attachments(i).attach_content)

  LOOP

    utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw(dbms_lob.substr(attachments(i).attach_content, n_amount, n_offset)));

    n_offset := n_offset + n_amount;

  END LOOP;

  utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('' || UTL_TCP.crlf));

        END LOOP;

         END IF;

        -- Last boundry

        utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('--' || v_boundry || '--' || UTL_TCP.crlf));



          -- Close data

           utl_smtp.close_data(conn);

            utl_smtp.quit(conn);



           EXCEPTION

            WHEN OTHERS THEN

             v_error_msg := 'Error in PKG_SEND_MAIL. '||sqlerrm;

              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_error_msg);



                END;



                END;
```

They tested this on a localhost DB server. It worked fine. When it was handed over to me for a testing in a DB environment which is not a localhost. It does not work as expected. Getting the error "ORA-29278: SMTP transient error: 421 Service not available". What could have gone wrong? Can someone help me out here.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with the code for the procedure and details of any setup/permissions that you have used.

Comment: Have you established that the problem is still at the DB end - rather than, say, the smtp server rejecting it (maybe silently)? Your DB server may need to be whitelisted as a valid email source, for instance.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your suggestion. I even verified it with my infra team, no authentication is in place at their end for accessing the smtp server. Is there any possibilities that the port they provided with me might not be open for connection? I believe whitelisting is not very much different from authentication. If I am wrong, kindly correct me.

Comment: Whitelisting and authentication are quite different, but I imagine they'd have mentioned it if they were doing it. If the port (or address) was wrong or blocked you would probably get a different error in PL/SQL. Can they see the traffic coming in - maybe in the smtp logs, or looking on the DB server and/or smtp server while you make the attempt to see if something is happening at network level?

Comment: My infra team said there can't see any incoming mail traffic from the DB end. So, can we establish now that there is an issue at the DB end.